# Can I trigger device-width media query when browser is dragged to different monitor

Tags: css, media-queries

I have a media query that is triggered based on device-width which works perfectly if a browser window is opened in a specific monitor (e.g. 1920x1080 vs. 1024x768), but if I drag my browser from one monitor to the other, the media query doesn't trigger.  Is there a solution to this?

Example: (.my-box should be blue on a big device, and red on a small device)

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1030) {
    .my-box {background: red;}
}
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 1030) {
    .my-box {background: blue;}
}
```